# Datarescue with ddrescue location of files

Tags: ntfs, ddrescue

I am recovering a 2TB harddisk with one NTFS partition with ddrescue. Only 300GB of the 2TB are used (mainly photos).

My problem is that I have not 2TB availbable on the rescue pc. Can I assume that the files are located at the first half of the harddisk? Or should I image the whole disk (I can split the image, using the logfile)

The recovering process is really slow. Right now ddrescue gives 62 days to go. I recoverd 250GB till now.

The precise command I used was

```
ddrescue -r 3 -C /dev/sda ./extschijf2 ./log.txt
```

Comment: If the disk is dying you're going to need to replace it. Why not replace it today? And then you have a target disk to use for recovery.

Comment: "_Can I assume that the files are located at the first half of the harddisk?_" probably but not necessarily.

Comment: What settings did you give to `ddrescue`? Bad settings can be a major source of slowness. As can a faulty disk (unsurprisingly).

Comment: @roaima I think we're thinking among the same lines.  Want me to delete my answer until OP comes back?

Comment: Thank you for the coments. The disk is not mine (family member), and I have no extra disk right now. I will update the topic with the ddrescue command used.

Comment: @Fabby, not at all. The `--sparse` option looks a useful possibility. +1

Comment: Thanks for the acceptance, question upvoted! **;-)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, NTFS has a tendency to allocate blocks at the beginning of a disk, but this is not necessarily so *for all blocks*.
2. `ddrescue` has a `--sparse` option that:

> --sparse
>
> Use sparse writes for outfile. (The blocks of zeros are not actually allocated on disc). May save a lot of disc space in some cases. Not all systems support this. Only regular files can be sparse.

*However*, not having the entire drive but only a part will make final recovery more difficult so: why not order a 2TB drive and have it shipped to you so that you *can* recover close to 100% of all data?  You should have enough time to to that looking at the time it'll take you to finish the job (62 days)...

Comment: Reading the answer, and the comments above, I will contact my family member to buy a new harddisk. Probably better then the sparse option. If he will not buy a new disk, the risk for lost data is on his side.